# React Native, Andoid: input loses focus when icon clicked

Tags: android, react-native, input

Faced an unexpected obstacle - when I click on the icon to clear the input, the focus from the input is lost and the click is not processed.
This only happens on Android. IOS is fine.

```
const onBlurHandler = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputFocusEventData>) => {
    onBlur && onBlur(e);
    setFocusOff();
  };

  const onFocusHandler = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputFocusEventData>) => {
    onFocus && onFocus(e);
    setFocusOn();
  };
```

```
<TextInput
        {...inputProps}
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
        onFocus={(e) => onFocusHandler(e)}
        onBlur={(e) => onBlurHandler(e)}
        placeholderTextColor={colors.light.grayscale[300]}
        style={[lightInput.input, isFocusedStyles, isNonEditableStyles, isDisabledStyles, isErrorStyles]}
        editable={enabled}
        selectTextOnFocus={enabled}
        value={value}
      />

      {isInputFilled && !error && editable && enabled && (
        <View style={lightInput.icon}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onInputClear}>
            <Close width={18} height={18} color={colors.light.grayscale[300]} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
```

Close icon has absolut position.

I tried use e.stopPropagation() and some other tricks, but it doesn't work anyway.(

Answer (score 0):

Because your delete button is a button, it gets focused when pressed.

To solve this issue, you can simply create a reference `textInputRef` for your textinput and call `textInputRef.current.focus()` in your `onInputClear` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for your answers.
Also I found this solution:

add to ScrollView prop keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
Also works!